# Symfony 2.8 Autowiring for method injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

> Update 2020 (this should have been much sooner). There can be a new class for each controller action. Each controller can be named by the action it is going to do, with an `Invoke()` method. [Consider "Action Domain Responder" (ADR)](https://github.com/pmjones/adr-example).
>
> Why do I want to do this? Controllers do not necessarily adhere to SRP, and I'm not about to go creating a new class for each of, what is effectively, a controller 'action'. Therefore, a controller should not have *everything* injected via constructor, but the relevant method being called should be able to state explicitly "I require these objects" and another method "these other objects".

[As of Symfony 2.8](https://dunglas.fr/2015/10/new-in-symfony-2-83-0-services-autowiring/), the Dependency Injection component now provides auto-wiring for your services if you provide `autowire: true` in `services.yml`.

I'm defining my controller as a service, like so:

```
test_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\TestController
    autowire: true
```

My controller looks as follows:

```php
class TestController
{
    public function indexAction(TestClass1 $tc1, $id)
    {
        return new Response('The slug is: ' . $id);
    }
}
```

You will notice I'm typehinting for `TestClass`, which is just an empty class. However, the following error appears when I refresh the page:

[image: Method Injection Symfony Autowiring Error]

What do I need to change in my `services.yml` file to have auto wiring dependency injection in my controller method? Just a note, the issue *isn't* because I have an `$id` 'slug' afterwards. Removing it does nothing.

Comment: But did you have "use xxx\TestClass1;" on top of your controller? Not sure if you need do something for controller actions in "services.yml".

Comment: Of course I imported the namespace :P I was looking for something for controller actions in `services.yml`, I found references to a `calls:` key scattered around the internet but nothing in the symfony docs or anything that worked.

Comment: I doubt if your approach can work.  indexAction is being called by the router.  The container was used to create the controller but I don't see how it could be part of the routing process.

Comment: @Jimbo, good. Yes, try put $id as first parameter. I'm using next construction for controllers: `public function updateAction($idCategory, Request $request)` and it works, no need anything in services.yml...

Comment: Because `auto wire:`  should be `autowire:` And also this can be done only in constructor I think.

Comment: `auto wire` was a typo my mac put in. It is `autowire` :)

Comment: You're trying to do this on an action, I'm not sure that it will work that way, given that the action's parameters are supposed to be the things passed in by the router. The DI injects via method calls (and you don't want to call your action), and the constructor. You need to make a constructor with all of the controller's dependencies.

Comment: @VladimirGilevich That's because `Request` is automatically injected by the framework if you type hint for it. I'm talking about my own custom objects.

Comment: @Seer The functionality is: (1) Read controller constructor signature (2) Recursively instantiate (3) Read method needed to be called (4) Recursively Instantiate on call. The method to perform (1) and (3) are identical, it's just introspection.

Comment: @Jimbo Got you. OK, if it is not possible for custom objects, then you can just describe in services.yml your object and use it in controllers via `$this->get('name_from_services')`...

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Appreciate the comment but `$this->get()` is a service locator and not dependency injection.

Comment: @Jimbo Yes, yes, it is not DI. Just another variant that can be useful. If you find way how to implement DI with custom objects in controllers - update here - would nice to know too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I've created a bundle allowing to do more or less what you want called [DunglasActionBundle](https://dunglas.fr/2016/01/dunglasactionbundle-symfony-controllers-redesigned/).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Symfony autowiring system.

The Symfony Dependency Injection Component (and the autowiring system is part of it) doesn't work that way. It only allows to automatically inject dependencies in the class constructor of services and knows nothing about controller classes, actions and other parts of the HttpKernel Component.

It's not currently possible to do what you want to do. Initially, the autowiring system has been designed for domain services, not for controllers.

It should be possible to bridge the autowiring system with controller parameters using [a custom param converter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter). However, I'll suggest you take another way [I've first described here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16863#issuecomment-162221353):

> There is another approach I want to discuss since several time but I
>   did not have the time to blog about it.
>
> It's a derivate of/similar to the ADR pattern, applied to Symfony.
>
> 1. An action is a single class with a `__invoke()` method containing all it's
>      logic (should be only some lines of glue code to call the domain and
>      the responder).
> 2. Actions are registered as a service (it can be
>      automated using a compiler pass and some conventions, similar to how
>      we discover controllers right now, with the ability to override the
>      definition if needed)
> 3. On such action services, autowiring is enabled.
>
> It means that almost as easy as current controllers to use for the
>   developper, but with an explicit dependency graph and a better
>   reusability. Only things that are really necessary are injected. In
>   fact, it's already doable to use such system with Symfony. We do it in
>   API Platform master. Here is one action for instance:
>   https://github.com/dunglas/DunglasApiBundle/blob/master/Action/PostCollectionAction.php
>
> In this implementation I also rely a lof on kernel events to be able
>   to plug and play some sort of logic (persistence, validation...) in a
>   decoupled manner but it's out of scope.

Comment: Any idea how to use autowiring with doctrine repository as a service?

Comment: @Gadelkareem https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/